# AWS Lambda (Python3.8) not able to connect to S3 buckets using Role

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

For some strange reason, Lambda (Python3.8) is not able to connect to S3 bucket using Role. It just returns **Timed Out** error. It does not even throw any exception. It **Times Out** when this section is called
`response = s3.list_buckets()`

I have even checked **flow log** of the **Lambda ENI**. They are returning **no-data**.

However, the same setting is working in another project.

**Here is the code sample:**

```
import json
import datetime
import time
import config as cf
import boto3
import botocore
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        # Retrieve the list of existing buckets
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        response = s3.list_buckets()
        
        # Output the bucket names
        print('Existing buckets:')
        for bucket in response['Buckets']:
            print(f'  {bucket["Name"]}')
        
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception:\n" + str(e))

    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Has anyone faced any such problem?

A little help/advice would be really appreciated, I have been struggling for the last 2 days and I have to submit my work.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,

Suman

Comment: Is the lambda running inside VPC?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54112422/access-aws-s3-from-lambda-within-default-vpc

Comment: Yes Same VPC @jellycsc

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I created my NAT Gateway using a Private Subnet. I changed the NAT Gateway to a Public Subnet and it worked like a charm.

I do not need a VPC Endpoint to connect to S3 or any other services which are within my VPC.